# Align vertically input elements in div

Tags: html, css

I've made a search on SO to know how can I align vertically **input** elements in a div. This div is inside a form. Most of questions, form elements have a lot of `<div>`'s for each element or a `<br>` tag for that.

[Vertically aligning input elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274572/vertically-aligning-input-elements)

[Vertical align with my inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28214780/vertical-align-with-my-inputs)

I've made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dmb3q6gz/) with this CSS:

```
.fillform{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 33%;
bottom: 0;
background: rgba(225, 43, 50, 1.0);
}

.fillform div{
position: absolute;
float: left;
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 2px solid rgba(0,0, 255, 1.0);
}

.fillform div input{
float: left;
display: inline-block;
border: 2px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0);
box-sizing: border-box;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Input elements can't be aligned vertically and have margins?

EDIT: I'll not use table or `display: table-cell;`

Comment: remove `float:left` on the inputs, just let the inputs in the natural flow

Comment: @ArnaudGueras It doesn't work. See for yourself. Removing float: left from input, they just gain spaces

Comment: remove `float: left;` and add `display: list-item;` and here is the [updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dmb3q6gz/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this rule:

```
.fillform div input{
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m9ev8etj/

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative;top: 50%;margin: 1px;` to your `.fillform div input` class and try this:

```
.fillform{
     width: 100%;
     height: 33%;
     bottom: 0;
     background: rgba(225, 43, 50, 1.0);
}

.fillform div{
     float: left;
     width: 100%;
     height: 200px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border: 2px solid rgba(0,0, 255, 1.0);
}

.fillform div input{
     float: left;
     border: 2px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0);
     box-sizing: border-box;
     position: relative;
     top: 50%;
     margin: 1px;
}
```